# How can one hide one's timezone on Slack?

Tags: slack

The time zone of a user is displayed by default

[image]

I am aware that the timezone can be changed manually (https://slack.com/help/articles/219889247-Manage-your-time-zone-preferences).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible.

The timezone field is one of the default profile fields. According to [Customize member profiles](https://slack.com/help/articles/212281478-Customize-member-profiles) workspace and org owners/admins can add new fields, but it doesn't mention that it's possible to edit, hide or delete default fields.

From the referred link:

> Who can use this feature?
> Workspace Owners/Admins and Org Owners/Admins
> Standard, Plus, and Enterprise Grid plans